# how to add script in html/jsx reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to add a style to a html element only when the property of an array of object has a certain value. but I got an error like this instead:

```
/src/App.js: Unexpected token, expected "..." (35:25)
```

here's my code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-violet-tfuu2e?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      id:1,
      score:10,
    },
    {
      id:2,
      score:20,
    },
    {
      id:3,
      score:50,
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {
        data.length > 0
        ? (
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>value</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {
                data.map((item, index) => (
                  <tr key={item.id}>
                    <td>{index+1}.</td>
                    <td {item.value > 10 ? 'style=\'backgroundColor:"red"\'' : ''}>
                      {item.value}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        )
        : (
          <div>
            <em>No data</em>
          </div>
        )
      }
      {
        data.map((item, index) => (

        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You’re trying to set a property of the table data element but you’re just putting a string there instead. Use an object and spread it into the TD props, or set the style *value* and use it in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td style={item.value > 10 ? { backgroundColor: "red" } : ""}>
```

The style attribute in React accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased properties rather than a CSS string. You can find more details [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style).